# Found the type of element selected by getSelection

Tags: javascript, xml, delphi, dom, xpcom

I need to know the type of item selected by getSelection:

```
Sel:=ContentWindow.GetSelection;
  Range:=Sel.GetRangeAt(0); // le premier élément selectioné
   sel.RemoveAllRanges();
  range.deleteContents();
  // obtenir l'alocation de la sélection courante
  Container:=Range.StartContainer;
```

> > > >
> > >       How to know that the selected object is an image or a table, or just a text link.
> > >         because I need to extract all property of each selected object.

Comment: The selection can contain multiple DOM nodes. Do you need to iterate over all of them?

Comment: I want to know quel'élément selected is a picture or a painting? it is how?

Answer (score 0):

once you have the item you want, then you can use the localName property.

```
var temp = document.getElementById("someid");
console.log(temp.localName);
```

If the element with the id="someid" was a div, then the console would have "div" in it.